# Expression must have (Pointer-to-) function type while using structs

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, struct

So basically what I'm doing is passing an array of structs from one function to another function. It works for the show functions, but not for the max functions :/ What exactly am i doing wrong?

```
void show( const ABC & x ){
    cout<<"{"<<x.n<<",'"<<x.c<<"',{"<<x.a[0]<<","<<x.a[1]<<","<<x.a[2]<<"}}";
}

void show( const ABC arr[], unsigned elements ){
    for(unsigned i=0; i<elements; i++)
        show(arr[i]);
}
```

the following doesn't work

```
double max( const ABC & x ){
    double max=x.a[2];
    if(x.a[1]>max)
        max=x.a[1];
    if(x.a[0]>max)
        max=x.a[0];
    return max;
}

double max( const ABC arr[], unsigned elements ){
    double max=arr[2].a[3];
    for(unsigned i=0; i<elements; i++)
        if(max<max(arr[i])){
            max=max(arr[i]);
        }
    return max;
}
```

Comment: In the future consider making the error that your compiler gives you explicit. Cross-referencing the line(s) the error is pointing to is very helpful as well. It helps a lot in figuring out what is going on.

Comment: You may also want to replace the `const ABC arr[]` with `const ABC* arr`.  Both statements are probably equivalent, and you shouldn't have to modify anything that references 'arr', but if it's giving you some sort of access error it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your `double` variable to something else than `max`. As things are, it is hiding the functions that share the same name, hence why the call expression is invalid (you're trying to pass arguments to a `double`).

Comment: Oh wow thanks...that was a fail on my part. Not sure how i missed that haha